# Hide/Show of text using radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 sets of radio buttons and I want to show a text if all are selected and its value is "true" (Yes). Hide a text if at least 1 value is "false" (No).

My Page would look like:

```
 Are you eligible for this?           .Yes .No 
 Are you paying your bills monthly?   .Yes .No
 Do you have health insurance?        .Yes .No
```

I want to do this in jQuery, I've attached my code below!!

```
<div>Are you eligible for this?</div>
           <div>
                <div>
                    <label for="yes">Yes</label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" id="yes" value="true" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="no">No</label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" id="no" value="false" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>Are you paying your bills monthly?</div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label for="yes1">Yes</label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" id="yes1" value="true" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="no1">No</label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" id="no1" value="false" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>Do you have health insurance?</div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label for="yes2">Yes</label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" id="yes2" value="true" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="no2">No</label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" id="no2" value="false" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

The jQuery script I came up with:

```
$("input[name='mygroup']").change(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="true" && $(this).is(":checked")){
             //show
    }else{
            //hide
    }
});
```

Can we go with count of selected radio buttons?

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. You are welcome to bring something to get help with, but you won't get any support without having written some code yourself.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and you are more likely to get help. Check [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

You could do an `onClick` method that would check to see if all three radio buttons are true. Once that condition is met, just set the text to `display` however you want it to (e.g. `x.style.display = 'none'`)

Note: SO isn't for free coding, but if there is a principle or error you are having difficulty with, that can be addressed.

Comment: $(".class").each(function() {
 if($(this).attr("value")=="true" && $(this).is(":checked")) {
 //show 
 } else {
          //hide
 }
});  I'm able to check for at least one radio button is check but how to all 3 are checked and true?

Comment: `$('input:radio:checked').length` will return back how many radio buttons are checked. Assuming you only have three on the page, then just check to see if the amount that are checked is three. If so, then you run change the display value.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it did :)